# Is there a way to get eclipse code completion to filter options on text typed anywhere in a word rather than just the start?

Tags: eclipse

I have just started using eclipse Indigo for Scala development. Is there a setting anywhere in eclipse to change the filter behavior to "anywhere" when I type X. and invoke completion?

If I have an object foo with a field foo.name and methods foo.fullName, foo.capAllNames I would like all three to remain in the selection list when I type foo.name.

Currently the list is filtering on the start of the word so only the foo.name property would remain in the example given. I would like the filter to be based on the text being present anywhere in the word, can this be done in eclipse?

Thanks
John

Comment: I think the plugin 'Code Recommenders' does something like that. I'm not totally sure, but have a look at it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Code Recommenders as suggested by moeTi will do the job but I might have to wait for a while until the latest bug fixes filter through to a release that will play nicely with the Scala plug in (it/eclipse threw exceptions when I installed it):

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=383395